# Excluded embedded tomcat still exists in lib-provided folder

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven

I need to build spring-boot application as WAR. I did this:

```
<profile>
            <id>war</id>

            <properties>
                <packaging.type>war</packaging.type>
                <start-class>com.healthgorilla.analytics.AnalyticsApplication</start-class>
            </properties>

            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                    <scope>provided</scope>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </profile>
```

Maven builds WAr but I have this folder: `myApp-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war\WEB-INF\lib-provided` with this libraries:

[image]

tomcat-embedded still exists in my war artifact. How can I remove it?

I tried add this:

```
         <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
```

But the result is the same.

Comment: Misspelling? Did you mean the word “embedded” in your title?